# Is This Another Definition of A Homeomorphism?

Tags: general-topology

Suppose we have a map $ f: X \rightarrow Y $ where $ X $ and $ Y $ are topological spaces. Also suppose that $ U $ and $ V $ are open subsets of $ X. $

Suppose that $ V \supset U $ if and only if $ f(V) \supset f(U). $ Is this another way of saying that $ f $ is a homeomorphism? If so, why?

Comment: It’s not.  Counterexamples aren’t hard to come by.

Comment: Does this property imply anything about the map?

Comment: I don't think this implies anything particularly nice without further assumptions on your spaces (i.e. separation axioms)

Comment: It may imply that the function is an open map.

Comment: This might be it. I now see that the map in question is bijective, continuous and open. The author is attempting to show that it is also a homeomorphism, and he bases that claim on this property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $f$ to be the identity map from $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard topology to $\mathbb{R}$ with the discrete topology. Then for any two sets (even if they are not open) $U,V$ we have $U\subset V$ if and only if $f(U)\subset f(V)$. But obviously $f$ is not a homeomorphism. It is not even continuous.